# C++ Derived Class Accessing Base Class member

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Probably a very simple question, but I'm having a devil of a time figuring this out.  I have a base class:

```
class User
{
    public:
      User();
      ~User();
      void GetUser();
      void SetUser();
    protected:
      std::string name;
};
```

Here's my derived class:

```
class UserInfo: public User
{
  public:
    void GetUser();
};
```

And the methods:

```
User::User()
{
  name = "";
}

void User::GetUser()
{
  cout << name;
}

void User::SetUser()
{
  cin >> name;
}

User::~User()
{
  name = "";
}

void UserInfo::GetUser()
{
  cout << "  ";
  User::GetUser();
  cout << ", you entered: ";
}
```

Everything seems to work fine, but when I call UserInfo::GetUser() from the program, it doesn't execute or retrieve the value stored in the name member of the User class.  How do I get that value?  Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code that's shown (well, nothing that's directly relevant to the stated question). Therefore, the problem must be in the code that's not shown.

Comment: Show the code that calls GetUser(). Perhaps you wanted `virtual void GetUser();` instead of `void GetUser();` in class `User`.

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/PUMIM54797)

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Realized I was trying to use the wrong call to the method based on all the suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function names and what they do can be improved. Don't mix getting and setting member variables with `cin` or `cout`. I suggest changing the functions as follows.

```
class User
{
    public:
      User();
      ~User();

      // Make the Get function a const member function.
      // Return the name.
      std::string const& GetName() const;

      // Take the new name as input.
      // Set the name to the new name.
      void SetName(std::string const& newName);

    protected:
      std::string name;
};
```

and implement them as:

```
std::string const& User::GetName() const
{
  return name;
}

void User::SetName(std::string const& newName)
{
  name = newName;
}
```

After that, you don't need the `GetUser` member function in `UserInfo`.

When you are ready to set the name of a `User`, use:

```
User u;
std::string name;
std::cin >> name;
u.SetName(name);
```

This allows you to separate the setting of the name of a `User` from where you get that name from.

When you are ready to print the name a `User`, use:

```
std::cout << u.GetName();
```

This allows you to separate the getting of the name of a `User` from how you use the name after you get it.